# Conversion of Minute,Seconds to milliseconds

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldbox

We are working with millisecond conversion of time duration which is saved in database (Format : mm:ss ).The duration value we can access through the command #bignews.Control_CountdownDuration#.

```
  <div class="slideBox" data-duration="#bignews.Control_CountdownDuration#">
```

The current value(mm:ss) is not sufficient for proper working of data-duration.
 Can anyone guide me to complete the task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comination of `createTimeSpan()` and `dateDiff()` will do the job.
Input here goes into the variables `minutes` and `seconds`:

```
<cfset cmpBase              = createTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)>
<cfset cmpValue             = createTimeSpan(0, 0, minutes, seconds)> 
<cfset diffInSeconds        = dateDiff("s", cmpBase, cmpValue)>
<cfset diffInMilliseconds   = (diffInSeconds * 1000)>
```

Assuming your source value is stored as string like `mm:ss`, this would be:

```
<cfset minutes  = getToken(bignews.Control_CountdownDuration, 1, ":")>
<cfset seconds  = getToken(bignews.Control_CountdownDuration, 2, ":")>
<cfset cmpValue = createTimeSpan(0, 0, minutes, seconds)> 

<cfset cmpBase              = createTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)>
<cfset diffInSeconds        = dateDiff("s", cmpBase, cmpValue)>
<cfset diffInMilliseconds   = (diffInSeconds * 1000)>

    <div class="slideBox" data-duration="#diffInMilliseconds#">
```

*(Validation left out for readability.)*

On a side note: You should probably work with the total number of seconds (see variable `diffInSeconds`) since you don't have the milliseconds precision anyway.

Comment: Looks much more complicated than necessary.  To me the problem is as simple as splitting the string into minutes and seconds, mulitplying the minutes by 60, adding the seconds, and muliplying by 1000.

Comment: I had used the second part of code of  his answer to resolve the issue.